# How to get rid of water stain on concrete?

Tags: concrete, leak, cleaning

Hi there was a leaked pipe and the leaked water formed a trail on my concrete floor. Now the leak is fixed and I thought the water trail will just disappear when it dries up, but instead, it has moved and keeps on shifting to unaffected areas. Tried scrubbing it but its not on the surface. How do you get it out to restore the clean look of the concrete floor?

Comment: concrete is made of dirt,  what do t you mean "look clean"

Comment: I'm confused - your leak has been fixed, but there's still a water trail and it's moving? That indicates to me that there's still a leak, maybe from somewhere else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had a similar problem recently and I successfully used a solution of muriatic acid. I wouldn't use full strength because of its potency. You can purchase a mild muriatic solution in most hardware stores.
Make sure you wear protective gloves and eyewear. Pour it on according to directions, lightly scrub the area with a brush being careful not to splatter the solution. After the time indicated on the bottle rinse the area thoroughly.

Comment: I’ve use muriatic acid too. Very powerful. Follow directions on bottle.